# Any Url script to notify windows 10 webview

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, cordova-win10

From windows 8.1, `AllowedScriptNotifyUris` property of webview get obsoleted and intenseness asked to set URLs in `ApplicationContentUriRules` under package manifest file.

It wont allow to write `*` in the url matching criteria as mentioned below.

```
<uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
    <uap:Rule Match="*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
</uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

I am not sure what URL will be loaded in webview, i want either all url to notify the script or any other way of dynamically adding URL in manifest file.

Comment: were you able to figure that out ??

Comment: @CodeR No. let me know if you found any solution

Comment: do https://* instead of just *

Comment: @CodeR Still not working

Answer (score 1):

> To enable an external web page to fire the ScriptNotify event when
>   calling window.external.notify, you must include the page's URI in the
>   ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest. (You can do
>   this in Microsoft Visual Studio on the Content URIs tab of the
>   Package.appxmanifest designer.) The URIs in this list must use HTTPS,
>   and may contain subdomain wildcards (for example,
>   https://*.microsoft.com) but they cannot contain domain wildcards (for
>   example, https://*.com and https://*.*). The manifest requirement does
>   not apply to content that originates from the app package, uses an
>   ms-local-stream:// URI, or is loaded using NavigateToString.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should add wildcard for all sub domains as well.
Something like this:

```
<uap:Rule Match="https://*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
<uap:Rule Match="https://*.*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
<uap:Rule Match="https://*.*.*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
<uap:Rule Match="https://*.*.*.*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
<uap:Rule Match="https://*.*.*.*.*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
<uap:Rule Match="https://*.*.*.*.*.*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
<uap:Rule Match="https://*.*.*.*.*.*.*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
```

Be careful with this since it will expose all WinRT APIs to any url opens inside your app (webview). You may use `MSWebViewNavigationStarting` event on webview to monitor all navigations inside your webview.

Comment: This fails certification ! You have to hard code the domain

Answer (score 0):

As was written above reason is in URI rules. [Here is the answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f322a505-87af-42a1-b196-1143011ba327/uwpc-script-notify-webview-not-working) as well.

Here is my working example for localhost:
[image]